# Table locking issues with Laravel 5.1

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I can't lock MySQL tables with this query:

```
DB::statement('LOCK TABLES imports WRITE');
```

It gives those exception:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while
>   other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using
>   PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever
>   going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting
>   the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute. (SQL: LOCK TABLES
>   imports WRITE)

The same error occurs when I use PDO.

How i should use this?

Comment: Try  `DB::connection()->getPdo()->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);`.

Comment: Okay, I see in docs and you can only lock table for update or for share. You can do that using `DB::table('imports')->lock($lockUpdate);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// prevent rows from being modified until you're finished
DB::table('imports')->where('total', '>', 10)->sharedLock()->get();
```

Use `lockForUpdate()` to instead prevent rows from being modified or selected with another shared lock.

Comment: Hi, when is the lock released?

Comment: NB: sharedLock will lock write to a *row* (not a table). To answer your question, Supersan, it will release once the transaction is complete.

Comment: @jonlink , if i have 2 threads accessing my db and i am using sharedLock to avoid collision, what happen if the 2nd thread want to update through a transaction and cannot as the first transaction has the lock. Will the thread wait or just throw an error, which mean i need to catch it to re-try...or is there a wait time and time out?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to lock the whole table and you want to use `LOCK TABLES table_name WRITE` it should be called in this way `DB::unprepared('LOCK TABLES imports WRITE');` but if you only want to apply the lock on the selected rows then using `sharedLock()` or `lockForUpdate()` is the right way to do that so it will return and lock only the selected rows.

Comment: NB: this will lock the table for read *and* write. It will stay locked until `DB::unprepared('UNLOCK TABLES')` is used.